# Remmina TLS, NLA works, but high encryption fails

Tags: linux, rdp, encryption, tls

Remmina works fine with TLS and NLA. But if encryption is set to high instead of client compatible, then it stops working.

Questions:
1. Why setting high encryption prevents connectivity?
2. What's the meaning of encryption setting anyway, when using TLS connections?
3. Does it matter at all, when legacy RDP connections using RDP encryption aren't allowed.